# How to fetch the Rehire period of an employee

Tags: mysql

Dummy Table entries

[image: 1]

From above attached image , need to fetch the period when the project owner got rehired to a particular contract .
Basically ,query is required which can check whether the employee got rehired or not, if he is rehired then what's the period when he got hired back on that contract.
In the above example, a query should return the rehire period as 202209 for the employee '1'.

A query to fetch the rehire period of an employee

Comment: If the owner 2 row were not there, is it a rehire? In other words, what makes a rehire, nonconsecutive periods, or someone else being the owner in between?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have multiple rows for the same contract and period?

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: If an employee has multiple rehires, do you want them all, or just the latest?

Comment: Please publish representative sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Period Contract  Project_owner 
202004 0N0X0247  1110940 
202005 0N0X0247  1110940 
202006 0N0X0247  1110940 
202007 0N0X0247  1259902 
202008 0N0X0247  1259902 
202009 0N0X0247  1110940 
202010 0N0X0247  1110940 


Consider this as a sample data
Output: Project_owner : 1110940 
Rehire Period : 202009

Comment: Also if the employee has multiple rehires i want all of them

Answer (score 0):

This could help :

```
select max(c.period)
from contracts c 
inner join 
(
    select project_owner, min(period) as period 
    from contracts c
    group by project_owner
) as s on s.project_owner = c.project_owner and s.period < c.period;
```

Comment: This query is fetching all the periods which are more than minimum period of that employee
But i require only the rehire period